# Properly specifying model input sizes when instantiating and fitting simple keras model?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

We are just getting started with `keras` in class and I seem to be stuck on part of my first assignment. To start we are to build a simple perceptron within `keras` then train and test it against various truth tables.

I have started with the simple Not relationship. For the input and output I have generated two `(2, 1)` shaped matrices in `numpy` representing the Not relationship. I then programmatically generate the model based on the shapes of the input and output (for use later in the assignment). Though when it comes time to fit the model the input dimensions of the data are wrong for a reason I do not understand. `keras` produces the error

> ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected dense_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (2, 1)

Here is a SSCCE that reproduces the issue (Obviously you need `keras` and `numpy` to run it)

```
import keras
import numpy as np

# Shape(s): (2, 1)
xONE = np.mat([[0], [1]])
yNOT = np.mat([[1], [0]])

def generateModel(xShape, yShape):
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(yShape[0], input_shape = xShape))
    model.add(keras.layers.Activation('hard_sigmoid'))
    model.summary()
    return model

model = generateModel(xONE.shape, yNOT.shape)
model.compile(
    optimizer = 'adam', 
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
    metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(xONE, yNOT, epochs = 200, batch_size = 2, verbose = 1)
score = model.evaluate(xONE, yNOT, batch_size = 2)

print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

My only idea is that `model.fit` is expecting a bias term to be present in the input data as a result of the use of the `use_bias = True` param during the model generation? But this would just mean that it expects a input of shape `(3, 1)` not a 3-dimensional input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the row

```
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(yShape[0], input_shape = xShape))
```

into:

```
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(yShape[1], input_dim = xShape[1]))
```

The reason is that the dimension that required is the dimension of every data sample. When you used `yShape[0]` you passed instead the total number of samples. Similar issue happened with `input_shape = xShape`.

Comment: Ahh ok, I had some come close to this on my own after reviewing the output of `model.summary()` closely, but not exactly that. But it makes sense now. Thanks!